# Which condition?

Tags: pattern-matching, conditional, expression-test

I want to substitute integers in a list with theirs square, I tried these

```
Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5}}, t__ /; Element[t, Integers] :> t^2]
(*{{1, 4, 9}, {16, 25}}*)
Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5}}, t__ /; IntegerQ[t] :> t^2]
(*{}*)
```

Why the first code works and the second doesn't?
What is the difference between `Element` and `IntegerQ`?

Comment: Consider using `Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, s, {4, 5}}, t : {__Integer} :> t^2]` instead.

Comment: Or `Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, s, {4, 5}}, t : {__Integer}]^2`. Or `{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5}} /. t_Integer :> t^2` (or `t_?IntegerQ` to be safer), if "substitute" is interpreted strictly.  You might also be interested in [`PatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternSequence.html), although I don't think it's the thing to use here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

basically if you deconstruct you will see that [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html) in your case operates on the sublist level

```
{1, 2, 3} ∈ Integers
(* True *)

a ∈ Integers (* does not result in a boolean *)

{4,5} ∈ Integers
(* True *)
```

in second case your integers are present at level 2 and therefore you need to define the appropriate level in `Cases`

```
Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5}}, t__ /; IntegerQ[t] :> t^2, {2}]
(* {1,4,9,16,25} *)
```

Note: this will not give the same form as `Cases` with `Elements` because you are matching objects at a different level

If you need a similar result with your second case, consider using this:

```
Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5}}, pat : {__Integer} :> pat^2]
(* {{1, 4, 9}, {16, 25}} *)
```

with the named pattern `pat` your pattern matches at the same level as your `Elements` case

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for cleaning it up. always wondered how do you replace \[Element] by its symbolic form

Comment: Both parts of my edit were made using halirutan's excellent editor extension; see: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/121